# Submit results of a bash command to python script as sys.argv[1:]

Tags: python, bash, argv, sys

I have a list of files to be used as input that is very long. I was looking at the file input module, which seems to have some attractive features, [[https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html][1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html%5d%5b1%5d)

But I could not figure out how to use it without entering each file name by hand, which would be prohibitively long.

What I would love to do is submit something like

```
python myscript.py (ls -d -1 dir/* | grep summary.txt)
```

Or I could push this same bash command to filelist.txt and submit that way; either way the trick would be to submit without having to type each file.

Comment: Maybe this will work: `ls -d -1 dir/* | xargs grep summary.txt | xargs python myscript.py
`

Comment: You should probably not be calling on an external utility to generate the file names to begin with. Python is perfectly capable of all of that. Never [use ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in a program either.

Comment: What are the contents of `summary.txt`? Under no circumstances should you be processing the output of `ls`. (Also, `grep` reads from standard input *or* a file argument, not both.)

Comment: @chepner - why "under no circumstances" could you help me understand why this is bad practice?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [os package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) or [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). You would just have to figure out the exact command you would need to run in the terminal then read it and split it.

```
import os
files = os.popen('ls').read()
# "file1\nfile2\nfile3\nfile4"
files.rsplit()
# ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
```

Now you have a list of inputs that you can pass to the function

Comment: Use `os.listdir` instead of a pipe to `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure **you cannot use `sys.argv` for this.** Try using `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
import subprocess
args = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-d', '-1', 'dir/*', '|', 'grep', 'summary.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = args.communicate()
#Do something with out
```

Comment: This won't work. `ls` doesn't understand globs and definitely can't create a pipe or execute the grep utility. You should be executing a shell (or better, not relying on external programs for this simple task at all).